# Uploaded Google Drive file can't be updated via API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api

I would like to ask for your help regarding the updating of a file on Google Drive.
I created a XLSX file locally and uploaded it to GD. In my frontend I then append a row to the XLSX. This updated XLSX should then be updated/uploaded to GD and replace the old file.

The code snippet for the upload looks like this:

```
const res = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/${fileId}`?uploadType=multipart`, {
          mode: 'cors',
          method: 'PUT', 
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` },
          body: payload,
        });
```

This results in an error code 404, however I don't see why the permissions wouldn't be sufficient as I created the file with the same permissions.
I read that PUT should be used instead of PATCH, but that results in the same error.

I really don't know what to make of this because it works, if I do it like this:

```
const res = await fetch(`${Urls.upload}?uploadType=multipart`, {
          ...baseFetchOpts,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` },
          body: payload,
        });
```

But then a new file is created.

I would really appreciate your insights and help on this topic!

Regards,
Fabian

Comment: What is the full error message?  when you authenticated the user what scope did you request?    Why not use the Google apis js client library?

Comment: Thank you for your response, @DaImTo. Turns out that before this fetch call, the user folder was also tried to be PATCHed, which of course didn't work. I changed the code and it's now working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the reason for the error was that the created folder was also tried to be updated which of course doesn't work.
Fixed now.